# ngModel not update in input type in ionic 3

Tags: angular, html, ionic-framework, ionic3, one-time-password

after the sms getting otp not set in input type not set in value

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label >OTP Code</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" maxlength="4" id="smscode"  minlength="4"
              formControlName="password" placeholder="Your OTP Code"
              value="{{smscode}}"> 
   </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

```js
this.smscode=1234;

receiveSMS()
    {
    if(SMS)SMS.startWatch(function(){
    document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e)
     {
       var sms = e.data;

        if(sms.address=='IM-ODTMLT')
        {  
         this.smscode=sms.body.substr(28,4);
         alert( this.smscode);
         alert(JSON.stringify(sms));
         this.stopSMS();    
         } 
    });

}, 
function()
    {
      console.log('failed to start watching');
    });
}
```

---

```
<ion-input type="text" maxlength="4" id="smscode" minlength="4"
           formControlName="password"
           placeholder="Your OTP Code" value="{{smscode}}">
</ion-input>
```

this is a ionic code

Comment: <ion-input type="text" maxlength="4" id="smscode"  minlength="4" formControlName="password" placeholder="Your OTP Code"  value="{{smscode}}"></ion-input> 

 this is a ionic code

Comment: <ion-input type="text" maxlength="4" id="smscode" minlength="4" formControlName="password" placeholder="Your OTP Code" [(ngModel)]="smscode"></ion-input>

Answer (score 0):

The input needs an `ngModel` directive:

```
<ion-input type="text" maxlength="4" id="smscode" minlength="4"
           formControlName="password" placeholder="Your OTP Code"
           ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶s̶m̶s̶c̶o̶d̶e̶}̶}̶"̶
           [(ngModel)]="smscode">
</ion-input>
```

Comment: but after sms received  and otp getting but not update ngmodel